# tsql get the time stamp of files in a folder without using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, t-sql, timestamp, xp-cmdshell

I can't use xp_cmdshell due to security reason. Is there another way to get the time stamp of files in a folder without using xp_cmdshell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These guys created a CLR to replace the old xp_getfiledetails. http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/08/24/4400.aspx

I haven't installed it but it should be a place for you to start from.

Comment: i'm not allowed to add clr.

Comment: You can try using OLE Automation. If they turned off xp_cmdshell, they probably turned this off too. Here is a place to start. http://www.databasejournal.com/scripts/article.php/3443911/Check-File-Size.htm and http://www.mssqlcity.com/articles/general/oleautsp.htm